# Trying to make image slider loop

Tags: javascript, html

I made a slider with two images and i got it to change after a certain amount of seconds but i want it to return to the original image afterwards and not just stop.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bsu31hso/4/

```
<article>
        <div class="slider">
        <img id="pic1" src="images/main-banner.png" alt="main banner" class="main_banner">
        <img id="pic2" src="images/nutrition-banner.png" alt="nutrition banner" class="main_banner ">
        </div>
</article>




<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#pic1").show(function(){
            $("#pic1").fadeOut(5000);
            $("#pic2").fadeIn();

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: is the num of images fixed?

Comment: why dont you use slider plugins already present like https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4

Comment: you could use two functions and loop through them continously (if the number of images is fixed)

Comment: check out the demo I have updated it for you !!
if you understand this I am happy to tell you how to improve it and make smooth sliding effects

Answer (score 1):

**Few Points :**

1) what you did is not a slider.. doesn't go with the definition

if you want to make a slider user jQuery `animate()` with horizontal sliding

2) to slide images use `setInterval()` with desired time interval

3) one basic way is to use circular array to continue traversing in the same values over and over again

4) use `is(":visible")` check on each array element containing the id of each image which will help in detecting if it is visible and it has been selected time since then then increase the index of array for the next image to show  by sliding it using `animate()`

hope you understood!

**Here I have done code for you**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8q75qqnd/)